# Ubuntu failing to detect network

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ethernet, lan

We recently bought a machine with two on-board ethernet ports. However Ubuntu failed to identify network on either of the ports. Our guess is it might be due to incompatibility with drivers and new hardware (motherboard).

This is the motherboard information.

```
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: FUJITSU
        Product Name: D3348-B2
        Version: S26361-D3348-B2
```

and two of the on-board ethernet ports,

```
description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       logical name: enp0s25


description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       logical name: enp7s0
```

Whenever ports are plugged with cable, network icon tries to detect for a while and ultimately fails to identify the network. Proxy settings are of no issue here since other systems with same network configuration work fine with no issue.

running `ifconfig` from terminal shows below output.

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:1b:0e:a9:a4:dc  
          inet6 addr: fe80::72c7:256d:9308:384/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:256 (256.0 B)  TX bytes:5787 (5.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb300000-fb320000 

enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:1b:0e:e3:1e:a8  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:fb100000-fb17ffff 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:20264 (20.2 KB)  TX bytes:20264 (20.2 KB)
```

Can anyone suggest if something is missing or need to be tuned ?

EDIT:

```
$ dmesg | grep -e enp -e e100
[    2.570344] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    2.570345] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    2.574494] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.753736] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
[    2.753740] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 90:1b:0e:a9:a4:dc
[    2.753742] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.753789] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    2.754492] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[    2.804752] igb 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from eth0
[   13.526902] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
[   13.573026] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
[   13.575124] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   13.781179] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   16.619195] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   16.619236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
```

EDIT2:

```
sudo ethtool enp0s25 | grep Link
[sudo] password for epicwl: 
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -e enp -e e100` If the output is lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: The last two lines suggest that everything is perfectly fine. Is there still no *inet addr* in `ifconfig`?  What does this tell us? `sudo ethtool enp0s25 | grep Link` Is Network Manager running here?

Comment: @chili555 Hi I have updated the post. It seems to detect the network. I tried both the ports (enp7s0 and enp0s25) and its the same output. There is no IPV4 in `ifconfig` and network manager is running.

Answer (score 0):

This strange thing happens with me too. I have solved it by deleting the old network setting and created new one. But not sure will this work for you too.

1) At your right-hand corner top click on network > edit connections . You will get a small popup like the one below.

[image]

2) Delete all the network settings.

3) Re-add then and try to connect.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. I have already tried this, didn;t work :|